# How can I display a menu item's contents without clicking on the item

Tags: templates, knockout.js, menu

I would like to display the contents of the first menu item, without clicking on it, making it the default contents displayed when the app is opened. I have tried everything I can think of. Console.log shows the value of the "selectedView" observable to be something like "View {title: "Event List", templateName: "EventList"}" so I've tried setting it to this value but it still does work.

````
<div class="inServMenu" data-bind="foreach: views">
    <a href="#" class="inServMenuItem" data-bind="text: title, click: $root.selectedView"></a>
</div>

<div data-bind="with: selectedView">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: templateName }"></div>
</div>

<script id="EventList" type="text/html">
 <span>"Here's the Event List..."</span>
</script>

<script id="RosterList" type="text/html">
 <span>"Here's the Roster List..."</span>
</script> var View = function (title, templateName) {
    this.title = title;
    this.templateName = templateName;
};

// VIEWMODEL
var viewModel = {
    selectedView: ko.observable(),
    views: ko.observableArray([
        new View('Event List', 'EventList'),
        new View('Roster List', 'RosterList')
    ]),
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);```

[Here's a jsfiddle][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/jjfrick/hmfubkcr/18/
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to slightly change your viewmodel constructor so that you can have a reference to it:

```
function ViewModel () {
    var vm = this;
    vm.views = ko.observableArray([
        new View('Event List', 'EventList'),
        new View('Roster List', 'RosterList')
    ]);
    vm.selectedView = ko.observable(vm.views()[0])
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: Thank you Brother Woodrow. I've always used the "var viewModel " method vs the function, but it looks like my method has it's limitations. Do you find this to be true?